# Docker exec detach/attach functionality

Tags: docker

I have spent some time investigating resources, but did not find any suitable examples/documentation whether docker supports feature of attaching to 'exec' instance, or not.
Just to be clear/precise, let's say of following scenario:

1. Ubuntu docker container. Created as:

   ```
   docker container create -t -i --name ubuntuproject ubuntu:23.04
   ```
2. Starting container and attaching to it:

   ```
   docker start ubuntuproject
   docker attach ubuntuproject
   ```

   Now it runs fine as bash interactive instance.
3. Adding additional running instance(s) by command (root):

   ```
   docker exec -u 0 -it ubuntuproject bash
   ```

   Run and works okay, as expected
4. Detaching from previous (exec) instance using detach shortcut <ctrl + P -> q>

   Detaches from container as expected.

The questions are:

- Is step 4 really detaches exec session?
- Can this session be re-attached?

I know, that step 2 session can be detached and re-attached, but it is single tty session and not too handy when multiple screens / PCs needed (or am I wrong?).

I know, that it should be somewhere in documentation, but I simply atm can't find and would be grateful if someone would know pinpoint, if that's possible or not in docker.

Thanks,